# What does 1./diag(A) mean?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, diagonal

so I'm trying to study a code written in MATLAB. And there are these two strange lines of code, which I can't seem to understand, maybe someone could help me out? I'm new to MATLAB, I'm coding in C# most of the time.

As far as I know diag(A) means that it takes the members of main diagonal of matrix A. But what about the other parts of the line? Especially the 1./ operation, what does it do?

In the code below

> A is a 4x4 matrix, which stores double type values, b is the coefficients vector and alpha is a freely chosen vector (10, 5, 4, 2).

```
Atld=diag(1./diag(A))*A-diag(alpha)
btld=diag(1./diag(A))*b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diag(A)` returns a vector with the diagonal elements of matrix `A`
`./` is the element-wise division operator, so `1./diag(A)` inverts the elements from this vector.
`diag(1./diag(A))` returns the diagonal matrix from that vector

So, basically, `diag(1./diag(A))` is a matrix with the inverse of the diagonal of `A` on its diagonal, and zeros everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for response. Just to clarify, so if we have a matrix A which is `A=[
 5 11 7 0;
 2 6 17 2;
 2 1  5 1;
 4 12 1 7;]` then `diag(A) = 5 6 5 7` and `1./(diag(A)) = 7 5 6 5`, is that right?

Comment: If `diag(A) = 5 6 5 7` then `1./(diag(A)) = 1/5 1/6 1/5 1/7`

Comment: Oh, thank you, now it's all clear and I can move forward, appreciate it!